# Get the dictionary value in list using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Here my list of dictionaries:

```
ar = [{'employee_id': 20,
  'holiday_status_id': 2,
  'id': 2,
  'number_of_days': -1.0,
  'type': u'remove'},
 {'employee_id': 20,
  'holiday_status_id': 2,
  'id': 24,
  'number_of_days': 2.5,
  'type': u'add'},
 {'employee_id': 6,
  'holiday_status_id': 2,
  'id': 1,
  'number_of_days': -2.0,
  'type': u'remove'},
 {'employee_id': 8,
  'holiday_status_id': 2,
  'id': 25,
  'number_of_days': 6.0,
  'type': u'add'},
 {'employee_id': 7,
  'holiday_status_id': 2,
  'id': 22,
  'number_of_days': 6.0,
  'type': u'add'},
 {'employee_id': 9,
  'holiday_status_id': 2,
  'id': 26,
  'number_of_days': 6.0,
  'type': u'add'},
 {'employee_id': 9,
  'holiday_status_id': 2,
  'id': 76,
  'number_of_days': -1.0,
  'type': u'remove'},
 {'employee_id': 21,
  'holiday_status_id': 2,
  'id': 23,
  'number_of_days': 6.0,
  'type': u'add'},
 {'employee_id': 20,
  'holiday_status_id': 2,
  'id': 2,
  'number_of_days': -1.0,
  'type': u'remove'},
 {'employee_id': 20,
  'holiday_status_id': 2,
  'id': 24,
  'number_of_days': 2.5,
  'type': u'add'},
 {'employee_id': 9,
  'holiday_status_id': 2,
  'id': 26,
  'number_of_days': 6.0,
  'type': u'add'},
 {'employee_id': 9,
  'holiday_status_id': 2,
  'id': 76,
  'number_of_days': -1.0,
  'type': u'remove'}]
```

When I give `employee_id = 20` then need to get the related dictionaries and `id` should differ across the results.

Comment: You want only unique ID's?

Comment: Thanks for reply. yes, I want unique id with employee_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sets and generator function:

```
def solve(lis, employee_id):
    seen = set()
    for item in lis:
        if item['employee_id'] == employee_id and item['id'] not in seen:
            yield item
            seen.add(item['id'])

print list(solve(ar, 20))
```

**output:**

```
[{'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 2},
 {'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': 2.5, 'id': 24
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly I want this.

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension gives you all matching records:

```
[d for d in ar if d['employee_id'] == 20]
```

Demo:

```
>>> [d for d in ar if d['employee_id'] == 20]
[{'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 2}, {'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': 2.5, 'id': 24}, {'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 2}, {'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': 2.5, 'id': 24}]
```

That's 4 matching records, with ids 2, 24, 2 and 24 (it appears you doubled your example).

If you need unique entries, then you need to track what you already have seen; a `set` can do that for you:

```
seen = set()
entries = [d for d in ar if d['employee_id'] == 20 and d['id'] not in seen and not seen.add(d['id'])]
```

This checks for the right employee id, checks the record id wasn't seen before, and adds unseen ids to the set.

Now only two entries are found:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> [d for d in ar if d['employee_id'] == 20 and d['id'] not in seen and not seen.add(d['id'])]
[{'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 2}, {'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': 2.5, 'id': 24}]
```

Note that this iterates through the whole dataset each time you search. You may be better off creating a permanent dictionary instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict

by_employee_id = defaultdict(list)
seen = set()
for entry in ar:
    if entry['id'] not in seen:
        by_employee_id[entry['employee_id']].append(entry)
        seen.add(entry['id'])
```

This builds a dictionary mapping employee ids to a list of *unique* records. Now querying this is a one-step cheap lookup:

```
by_employee_id[20]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> by_employee_id = defaultdict(list)
>>> seen = set()
>>> for entry in ar:
...     if entry['id'] not in seen:
...         by_employee_id[entry['employee_id']].append(entry)
...         seen.add(entry['id'])
... 
>>> by_employee_id[20]
[{'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 2}, {'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': 2.5, 'id': 24}]
>>> by_employee_id[9]
[{'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 9, 'number_of_days': 6.0, 'id': 26}, {'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 9, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 76}]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need unique id means 2, 24.

Comment: Thanks @Pieters. You also gave the exact answer. But I will accept the one answer only. I will give +1 vote. Thanks....

Comment: @dhana: Note that you want to avoid the scan each time; use the dictionary index if you are searching this structure more than once.

Comment: But your answer is awesome. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension get the dict's which have `employee_id` 20 like this

```
print [myDict for myDict in ar if myDict["employee_id"] == 20]
```

**Output**

```
[{'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 2},
 {'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': 2.5, 'id': 24},
 {'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 2},
 {'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': 2.5, 'id': 24}]
```

**Edit:** To get the unique elements based on id

```
result = dict()
for d in [myDict for myDict in ar if myDict["employee_id"] == 20]:
    if d["id"] not in result:
        result[d["id"]] = d
print [value for key, value in result.items()]
```

**Output**

```
[{'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': 2.5, 'id': 24},
 {'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. and also 'id' should be unique. It is repeated two times.

Comment: @dhana I updated my answer. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you using a list? Just have a single dictionary for all employees, here:

```
from collections import defaultdict
employees = defaultdict(list)
for employee in ar:
    employees[employee['employee_id']].append(employee)
```

Now all you need is to get the one(s) you want:

```
>>> employees[20]
[{'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 2}, {'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': 2.5, 'id': 24}, {'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 2}, {'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': 2.5, 'id': 24}]
```

If for some strange read you NEED to have each employee be his own dictionary in a list, then you can do this:

```
>>> [d for d in ar if d['employee_id'] == 20]
[{'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 2}, {'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': 2.5, 'id': 24}, {'type': u'remove', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': -1.0, 'id': 2}, {'type': u'add', 'holiday_status_id': 2, 'employee_id': 20, 'number_of_days': 2.5, 'id': 24}]
```

If you are doing this kind of action many times, it's best that you make it a dictionary to improve performance, iterating a list is not an easy task.